# Configuration of recording target by using the onvif interface

Tags: ip-camera, onvif

I have several cameras with Onvif profile S. Each has the current firmware installed.

It seems there is no possibility to configure the recording target by using the Onvif interface on this profile? (I found it in the core specifications, but the cameras are responding with errors on that method)

But it seems strange, since it's possible to configure the recording target by using the GUI and the vendors own API. (I have Axis and Samsung cameras)

Comment: Have a look at the communication with some packet sniffing software. Typically there are very manufacturer specific messages sent and received in this area of ONVIF implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried it by using WireShark, but was unable to find methods for this actions at this point. (To be honest.. I don't even know why the cameras have the profile S. The cameras have edge recording functionality and there is a special Onvif profile G for this kind of devices)

Comment: Perhaps the vendors implement this outside of the onvif protocol.

Comment: Yes, I fear this could be the case. The Axis cameras have an own API and I'm able to use this interface to do that.. But this makes the ONVIF API worthless for me, since I'm trying to accomplish a vendor independent implementation.. If I need to implement the storage configuration with vendor specific methods, I could use the API of the vendors for the whole functionality. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have an answer for my question.

Onvif defined the methods for configuring storage settings in the newest version, 2.5. Since my newest camera with the current firmware only supports 2.1, I simply do not own any camera with support for storage configuration and so I need to wait until the vendors implement the methods from newer specifications.